# Generically typing a d3 selection for multiple SVG element types

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I need a callback function that can be supplied to `call` for both `rect` and `circle` elements.

Something like this:

```
function commonStuff(selection:d3.Selection<PLACEHOLDER_TYPE, MyDataType, SVGGElement, unknown>) {
  selection
    .classed('my-class1', true)
    .classed('my-class2', true)
}
```

that could be called on both `rect` and `circle` elements like this:

```
nodes.append('rect').call(commonStuff)
nodes.append('circle').call(commonStuff)
```

The docs for d3.Selection say that

> The first generic "GElement" refers to the type of the selected element(s).

And *my problem is that I don't know what to set that type to* (I've labeled it `PLACEHOLDER_TYPE` above) in order to capture both types `SVGRectElement` and `SVGCircleElement`.

And if I set it to just `SVGRectElement`, I get the error `Type 'SVGCircleElement' is not assignable to type 'SVGRectElement'` and vice versa the other way.

If I set it to `SVGRectElement|SVGCircleElement` I get the same error.

And if I set it to the common parent of both types, `SVGGraphicsElement`, I also get the same error.

I have a feeling I should be passing a generic somehow, but I don't know enough about TypeScript to be able to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
function commonStuff<GType extends d3.BaseType, D>(
    selection: d3.Selection<GType, D, d3.BaseType, unknown>
) {
    selection
        .classed("my-class1", true)
        .classed("my-class2", true);
}
```

For example:

```
let nodes = d3.select("a");

nodes.append('rect').call(commonStuff);
nodes.append('circle').call(commonStuff);
```